# how can i order items based on a method

Tags: django

i wanna know how can i order a listView using a method , like here i wanna order my posts based on numbers of likes , i am using class based views ... here is my code

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    # content = models.TextField()
    content = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    post_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='post/cover')
    category = models.CharField(choices=LABEL_CHOICES, max_length=1)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='blogpost_like')

    def __str__(self):
       return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
       return reverse("core:detail", kwargs={
          'slug': self.slug
    })

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
       self.post_image.delete()
       super().delete(*args, **kwargs)

    @property
    def comment_numbers(self):
       return Comment.objects.filter(post=self).count()


    def number_of_likes(self):
       return self.likes.count()
```

views.py

```
class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'home.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    paginate_by = 6
    ordering = ['-date_created']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use a function to do that but you can write a query to do it. You would need to override `get_queryset` first of all then use the aggregation function `Count`:

```
from django.db.models import Count

class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'home.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    paginate_by = 6

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        queryset = queryset.annotate(
            number_of_likes=Count('likes')
        ).order_by('number_of_likes')
        return queryset
```

Comment: name 'Count' is not defined

Comment: @daraq you need to import it.. See the first line in my code block?

Comment: yeah sorry i forget to put a comment that i forget to import Count